# Netbeans 7.2.1 build issues

Tags: java, netbeans, classpath

I have the following problem: I made a Java application which works completely fine in Netbeans' runtime, but will not work after build. The libraries are included properly, here's what happens after trying to run it from command line:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
    at com.xuggle.ferry.JNIMemoryManager.<init>(JNIMemoryManager.java:861)
    at com.xuggle.ferry.JNIMemoryManager.<clinit>(JNIMemoryManager.java:860)

    at com.xuggle.mediatool.MediaWriter.<clinit>(MediaWriter.java:119)
    at com.xuggle.mediatool.ToolFactory.makeWriter(ToolFactory.java:149)
    at app.RepaintImpl$1.run(RepaintImpl.java:63)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    ... 6 more
```

Everything in NB is set to JDK 7, I believe my environmental variables are fine too:

```
CLASSPATH=C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\*;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\*;
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_09
PATH=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_09\bin;...
```

Here's the build log, what bothers me is the fact that Netbeans creates empty directories in the .jar file:

```
ant -f "C:\\Users\\Wojtek\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\VNC Streamer" clean jar
init:
deps-clean:
Updating property file: C:\Users\Wojtek\Documents\NetBeansProjects\VNC Streamer\build\built-clean.properties
Deleting directory C:\Users\Wojtek\Documents\NetBeansProjects\VNC Streamer\build
clean:
init:
deps-jar:
Created dir: C:\Users\Wojtek\Documents\NetBeansProjects\VNC Streamer\build
Updating property file: C:\Users\Wojtek\Documents\NetBeansProjects\VNC Streamer\build\built-jar.properties
Created dir: C:\Users\Wojtek\Documents\NetBeansProjects\VNC Streamer\build\classes
Created dir: C:\Users\Wojtek\Documents\NetBeansProjects\VNC Streamer\build\empty
Created dir: C:\Users\Wojtek\Documents\NetBeansProjects\VNC Streamer\build\generated-sources\ap-source-output
Compiling 87 source files to C:\Users\Wojtek\Documents\NetBeansProjects\VNC Streamer\build\classes
Note: C:\Users\Wojtek\Documents\NetBeansProjects\VNC Streamer\src\app\RepaintImpl.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Copying 1 file to C:\Users\Wojtek\Documents\NetBeansProjects\VNC Streamer\build\classes
Copied 25 empty directories to 24 empty directories under C:\Users\Wojtek\Documents\NetBeansProjects\VNC Streamer\build\classes
compile:
Created dir: C:\Users\Wojtek\Documents\NetBeansProjects\VNC Streamer\dist
Copying 1 file to C:\Users\Wojtek\Documents\NetBeansProjects\VNC Streamer\build
Copy libraries to C:\Users\Wojtek\Documents\NetBeansProjects\VNC Streamer\dist\lib.
Building jar: C:\Users\Wojtek\Documents\NetBeansProjects\VNC Streamer\dist\VNC_Streamer.jar
To run this application from the command line without Ant, try:
java -jar "C:\Users\Wojtek\Documents\NetBeansProjects\VNC Streamer\dist\VNC_Streamer.jar"
jar:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 7 seconds)
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you run `java -jar "C:\Users\Wojtek\Documents\NetBeansProjects\VNC Streamer\dist\VNC_Streamer.jar"` ? It seems a library is missing. Have you maybe added a library (in the project properties) only in the run tab, but not the compile tab maybe?

Comment: Yes, those errors come from the command line after executing the file like that. Also I checked the properties and everything seems to be in place.

Comment: I'd start by removing the `CLASSPATH` variable since it's an old practice and it might be causing problems with other settings.

Answer (score 1):

In the build directory resides the resulting jar and a directory lib.

So the class path should contain `./lib`. This can be set in the main jar in META-INF/MANIFEST.MF as Class-Path, so you do not need to add it from the command line.
Look with 7zip into the jar.

The current run has to happen from the (build) directory with main jar and lib subdirectory.

By the way, no need for the environment class path to contain JRE's bin.

Comment: Tried setting the classpath in the manifest file, still doesn't help.